# BIRT - Remove empty row from parameter

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

I have two cascading parameters that need to be set before you generate the report. 
The first one is an ID I am selecting and the the second one can be a list of values (an array) that are linked to the first ID.

I have managed the array with this line on the *beforeOpen* script

```
this.queryText=this.queryText.replace("999",params["ID_BOBJECT"].value.join(","));
```

and my query looks like this:

```
SELECT V_MOUVEMENT_1.*
FROM V_MOUVEMENT_1
WHERE V_MOUVEMENT_1.ID_BOBJECT IN (999)
```

My problem is that in the end, the list of my second parameter has a *blank* value first and when I am creating the list selecting all the values (including the empty one) I get an error that the value is not specified:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMDLL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only solution that worked is only this one:
[Solution](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/files/file/1038-removing-blank-line-in-multi-select-cascading-parameters/)

Too bad it works only from eclipse...

If I deploy my rptdesign to another application, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Hi, it's working for me : https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/216579/ and https://georgeh12.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/removing-blank-line-in-multi-select-cascading-parameters/. For Eclipse and my RCP application. Did you apply the same patch in your BIRT plugin in your application?

Comment: Well, that was the problem, that I couldn't apply the patch to my other application. In the end I changed my hole architecture in order to not use cascading parameters :)